# Convert date object in normal format

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, datetime

When I am using a Python object, I get:

```
2018-05-18 08:38:58+00:00
```

This is not the format I need. We need to convert to this data format:

```
2018-05-18 08:38:58
```

How can I convert this in Python/Django?

Example:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-05-18 10:05:06', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

It’s working fine, but how can I pass 2018-05-18 10:05:06 as database but database giving?

```
2018-05-18 08:38:58+00:00
```

```
infoDevice = Device.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
newDate = Device.last_notification_time
```

It’s giving 2018-05-18 08:38:58+00:00.

How can I check date as per 2018-05-18 08:38:58?

Comment: Can you elaborate the **context** of the problem?

Comment: Please add `Device` model

Comment: Not device model are not required I have implemented as per iphone etc Now its working fine as per changes

Comment: I read your answer, can you tell me the `type()` of `info.dbdatetime` ? That is, `print(type(info.dbdatetime))` ?

Comment: this is just related with database variable

Comment: abc= abc.objects.get(id=id)
datetime = str(abc.lastupdatedtime)

Comment: @Jerin Peter George  please check now its related with APIs and website setting

Comment: Is `lastupdatedtime` is a `DateTimeField()` (in `models.py`)?

Comment: When we are using newDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(abc, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") then its showing date as per required

Comment: @Jerin Peter George now my setting its working fine as per website and etc.

Comment: I think your code isn't efficent much for **a simple format coversion**. I just trying to understand your **exact** requrement and hence trying to give a **simple and neat answer** (based on my knowledge),however you've got  the working answer

Comment: When I have implemented python code with notification then we need to just update database as per required .

Comment: Now implemented and its working fine now, please check my last answer for that changes

Comment: What do you mean by *"as database but database giving"* and *"How can I check date as per 2018-05-18 08:38:58"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50445140/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have implemented code for Python changes. Now it’s working. We need to just change the time setting.

Get any date from the database and change as required.

```
newDateFor = str(info.dbdatetime)
new_dt = newDateFor.split('+')[0]
newDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
a = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
b = newDate
```

Implement any other functionality as per changes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Python `datetime.datetime` object, then

`datetime_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

will return a `string` with the specified format.

#### Example

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: datetime.utcnow()
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 21, 8, 59, 41, 369517)

In [3]: date_time_obj = datetime.utcnow()

In [4]: date_time_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[4]: '2018-05-21 08:59:55'
```

Comment: are you trying to convert the **DB datetime** object to `string`?